# How do I delete my Ask Ubuntu account?

Tags: discussion

How do I / can the appropriate person or system please delete my Ask Ubuntu account; it is not to my liking and I do not want to be associated with it. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

That's very unfortunate. :\

I'll delete your account for you now.